# MathJax: LaTeX vs MathML Notations

Tags: latex, mathjax, mathml

I have a question about **MathML** and **LaTeX notations** in **MathJax**. I developed a web-based app about mathematics using mathjax. At first, I decide to use LaTeX for writing math expressions. But now I find a plugin as a visual math editor that finally insert math equations using MathML notations and I have no problem about rendering or other thing.
My question is:
 **is there any difference between two above notations in performance, supporting or...?
 Which is better? (or there are not any difference)**
I read this post:
[Any reason to favor MathML syntax over TeX in MathJax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545010/any-reason-to-favor-mathml-syntax-over-tex-in-mathjax) 
but I want get more and robust info.

thanks.

Comment: I think MathJax converts TeX equations to MathML and renders it. When we rightclick we will be able to see the MathML code even if it is LaTeX.

Comment: yeah, your're right. I see it before. So you mean now that MathJax converts TeX to MathML at the end and render it, it's better to write MathML? As I said, I will not write whole MathML by the hand and editor will help.
any other help?

Comment: You could use LaTeX and TeX4ht to generate MathML from TeX.

Comment: http://www.csun.edu/~hcmth008/mathml/acc_tutorial.pdf